# Script Out of range Error in excel vba code

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting on following code

> "SCRIPT OUT OF RANGE"

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="XXX/XXXXX/XXXX/XX.xlsx"
det =DateAdd("d",-1,da)
dst =Format(det,"d-M-YYYY")
if(Worksheets(dst).Name <> "") then
  msgbox("Worksheet Exists!")
else
  msgbox("Worksheet Dosent Exist!")
End if
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you check worksheet exist is wrong. If the sheet isn't exist then it cannot take the name of the worksheet then it will alert "script out of range"

You can try this

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Set ws = Worksheets(dst)
If Not ws Is Nothing Then
   MsgBox ("Worksheet Exists!")
Else
   MsgBox ("Worksheet Dosent Exist!")
End If
```